# Why is this variably turning negative?

Tags: c++, collatz

So my error says that I don't have the rights to access this memory.
This is the code for it, I'm trying to get the collaz series working.
But my `n` is getting negative even though it shoudln't.

```
const int number = 1000000;

//Chain Vars-------------------
int chainLength = 0;
int startingNumber = 0;
int chain = 0;
int n = 0;
//----------------------------

for (int i = 2; i <= 1000000; i++)
{
    n = i;
    chain = 0;

    while (n != 1 && n >= i)
    {
        chain++;
        if ( (n % 2) == 0)
        {
            n = n / 2;
        }
        else
        {
            n = n * 3 + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pastebin: bad - posting code on SO: good.  Posting all code: bad - posting code related to question: good

Comment: *The same code in c# works just fine.*  -- **C# is not C++**

Comment: Off-by one error.   Indexing of arrays starts at zero, not 1.   If it worked in C#, you just got lucky - the code would be just as flawed in C# even if it appeared to work for your chosen test cases.

Comment: What does the error message actually say?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie an algorithm is an algorithm. Array bounds are array bounds. Both irrespective of language.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou You're late to the game. The code was not posted when I made the comment -- it was a "pastebin" link that I have no access to. Thus I am referring to the general "it works in C#"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `for` loop, you do:

```
for (int i = 2; i <= 1000000; i++)
{
    n = i;
    chain = 0;

    while (n != 1 && n >= i)
    {
        chain++;
        if ( (n % 2) == 0)
        {
            n = n / 2;
        }
        else
        {
            n = n * 3 + 1;
        }
    }

    //Store the chain length in cache
    cache[i] = chain + cache[n];
    //-------------------------------

    if (cache[i] > chainLength)
    {
        chainLength = cache[i];
        startingNumber = i;
    }
}
```

At some point `while (n != 1 && n >= i)` most likely ends up with `n` being greater than `1000000`. You'll then access `cache` (when you'll do `cache[n]`) out of bounds (which are `[0:1000000]`).

Add `std::cout << "i is " << i << std::endl;` before the `while` loop. Add 
`std::cout << "n is " << n << std::endl;` after. Run the program, you'll get (after some seconds):

```
...
i is 113381
n is 85036
i is 113382
n is 56691
i is 113383
n is -1812855948
Erreur de segmentation (core dumped)
```

Here you are. Now, you can use a debugger, identify the bug, fix the bug (most likely rework your loop), and make it work! ;-)

Tip: As `n` becomes negative, maybe it reached `int`'s max value...then simply use a bugger type (like `long long int` or uint64_t). Then, you'll most likely not get any overlow (unless you make `number` bugger).

C# does not manage memory as C++ does. You may get no error if accessing the array out of bounds here (or, as commented above, you just got lucky).  I'm not familiar with C#. Accessing arrays must always be avoided it may have undetermined behaviour (could or could not lead to a crash).

Comment: I haven't run it myself, but I can be 100% sure that after the loop exits n will either be == 1 or < 1000000.

Comment: I thought that "n != 1" would only end if it is 1 ... how would i fix that? i can't seem to find the fix :/

Comment: @sLowDowN - or.. if `n` gets negative - see my post :)

Comment: @Danny_ds I'm the one who upvoted your answer as it's the only correct one so far. But why do you say "not so"? I know n goes negative, and my 100% certainty that n == 1 or < 1000000 still remains valid when n is negative.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou - Well, yes you're right about n being < 1000000 :) I thought you meant n would not be out of bounds for `cache[]`. And it only gets negative because gets too high. I'll remove that comment. Thanks for the upvote.

Comment: @jpo38 C# always does bounds checking on array accesses (unless the compiler can check the bounds statically). In contrast, C++ typically does not do bounds checking but instead exhibits undefined behaviour. Most compilers will add bounds checking if you specify "debug mode".

Answer (score 1):

After running and debugging the program:

```
    //Store the chain length in cache
    cache[i] = chain + cache[n];
```

`n` seems to be `0x93f20374` (at `i` being `113383`) which is negative `-1812855948`, or would be positive `2482111348` - but overflows to become `-1812855948`.

```
while (n != 1 && n >= i)
```

Loop ends with negative `n`, causing `cache[n]` to crash.

Comment: how can n get get to negative? Because n only divides by 2 or multiplies by 3 +1 ... this should be a really easy solution but i can't see it :D

Comment: @sLowDowN - Because it overflows `n` is a signed int, and gets to +2482111348 (unsignded), which converts to -1812855948 with an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Like jpo38 said :

Tip: As n becomes negative, maybe it reached int's max value...use a debugger to verify that, simply do, before your while loop:

That was my problem, i then changed "int n" to "long long n" because "long n" was still to small and now it gives me the right answer. Thanks everyone :) So easy but sometimes it's the small things you don't see.

Comment: Damned....I mentioned the overflow in my post but why am I not getting any more reputation for that! :-(

Comment: This got me thinking: can it be mathematically proven that n is not going to overflow when you use 64-bit integers?